# Symfony HttpFoundation UploadedFile "not uploaded due to unknown error" when using Doctrine DataFixtures

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3, is-uploaded-file

I've been using my Attachment entity based on the cookbook recipie [How To Handle File Uploads With Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) in Symfony 2.3.

It works well, even in functional tests. However using it with Doctrine DataFixtures is causing me problems.

> `[Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException]
>
>   The file "o-rly-copy.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.`

This was not helpful, however I did run `php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load -v` to bring up a stack trace and it appears the exception is thrown not on the persisting method, but on `$manager->flush()`

`Attachment::setFile()` requires an instance of `UploadedFile` so I wonder if there is a way round that.

It appears the error occurs on line 225 of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`

```
return $this->test ? $isOk : $isOk && is_uploaded_file($this->getPathname())
```

The condition for `is_uploaded_file()` returns `false` because the file was already on the server.

```
<?php

/**
 * Prepopulate the database with image attachments.
 */
final class AttachmentFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private static $imageData = array(
        array(
            'name' => "O RLY?",
            'file' => "o-rly",
            'type' => "jpg",
        ),
        //...
    );

    public function getPathToImages()
    {
        return $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/public/default/images';
    }

    public function getPathToUploads()
    {
        return $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/uploads/fixtures';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $imageReferences = array();
        $filesystem = $this->container->get('filesystem');

        foreach (self::$imageData as $image) {
            $imageFilename         = sprintf('%s.%s',      $image['file'], $image['type']);
            $copiedImageFilename   = sprintf('%s-copy.%s', $image['file'], $image['type']);

            $pathToImageFile = sprintf('%s/%s', $this->getPathToImages(), $imageFilename);

            try {
                $filesystem->copy($pathToImageFile, $pathToCopiedFile = sprintf('%s/%s', $this->getPathToUploads(), $copiedImageFilename));
                $filesystem->chmod($pathToCopiedFile, 0664);
            } catch (IOException $e) {
                $this->container->get('logger')->err("An error occurred while copying the file or changing permissions.");
            }

            $imageFile = new UploadedFile(
                $pathToCopiedFile,                                              // The full temporary path to the file
                $copiedImageFilename,                                           // The original file name
                'image/' . 'jpg' === $image['type'] ? 'jpeg' : $image['type'],  // Mime type - The type of the file as would be provided by PHP
                filesize($pathToCopiedFile),
                null,
                null,
                true
            );

            $imageAttachment = new Attachment();

            $imageAttachment->setName($image['name']);
            $imageAttachment->setFile($imageFile);

            // Populate a reference array for later use
            $imageReferences['attachment-'.$image['file']] = $imageAttachment;

            $manager->persist($imageAttachment);
        }

        $manager->flush(); // <-- Exception throw here


        // Create references for each image to be used by other entities that
        // maintain a relationship with that image.
        foreach ($imageReferences as $referenceName => $image) {
            $this->addReference($referenceName, $image);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Thanks to stof](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9113), the solution is to make `Attachment::setFile()` (or `Document::setFile()` if using the cookbook example) hint for an instance of `UploadedFile`'s parent class, `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`, and in the fixtures class, create a new instance and pass it to the setFile method

**Attachment.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
//...

class Attachment
{
    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param File $file
     */
    public function setFile(File $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        // check if we have an old image path
        if (isset($this->path)) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->path;
            $this->path = null;
        } else {
            $this->path = 'initial';
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

**AttachmentFixtures.php**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
//...

class AttachmentFixtures //...
{
    //...

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        //...
        $imageFile = new File($pathToCopiedFile);

        $imageAttachment = new Attachment();

        $imageAttachment->setFile($imageFile);
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

**There is now a better solution:**

The constructor of `UploadedFile` has a boolean `$test` parameter which disables the check using `is_uploaded_file`. This parameter has been added for testing/fixture code.

Just set it to true and the `isValid()` check of `UploadedFile` will not be a problem anymore.

Example:

```
// My data fixture code.
$test = true;
$userPhoto->setImageFile(new UploadedFile($photoDir . $photoFile, $photoFile, null, null, null, $test));
```

Comment: this is gonna delete the original file .while you have to deal with the tmp file .

Comment: if test =  true, then the original file will not be deleted ... In cas we want to delete the file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Filesystem` to upload files from fixtures first:

```php
const IMAGE_PATH = "/.../your_image_dir_from_this_dir/your_image.jpg";
const UPLOAD_DIR = "/.../your_upload_dir_from_this_dir";
const FILENAME = "your_image.jpg";

$filesystem = new Filesystem();
$file = __DIR__ . self::IMAGE_PATH;
$filesystem->copy($file, __DIR__ . self::UPLOAD_DIR . self::FILENAME);
```