# Recover original file name

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've [followed the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) in order to add a file variable into my custom entity, although the original file name is not stored for security issues.

Next, to make possible loading files like doctrine datafixtures, [I've modified class UploadedFile for File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978295/symfony-httpfoundation-uploadedfile-not-uploaded-due-to-unknown-error-when-usi).

My question is: If I'm using [viewer.js](http://viewerjs.org/) plugin to view PDF in my web, but this plugin needs original file name, How I recover original file name?